# Ways to circumvent lack of multiple inheritance acceptably in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm making a game. I have an Entity class which is a pair of x,y coordinates and width and height.

I want to subclass this Entity class into quite a few new classes to add combinations of groups of features. There are several "groups" of features that I want to add:

```
Moveable {
    public float getVelocityX();
    public void setVelocityX(float velocityX);
    public float getVelocityY();
    public void setVelocityY(float velocityY);
    public void moveRelative(float dx, float dy);
    public void setPosX(float posX);
}
```

and

```
Rotatable {
    public void setAngularVelocity(float degreesPerSecond);
    public void setAbsoluteAngle(float angle);
}
```

and

```
Resizable {
    void setAbsoluteSize(int width, int height);
    void setRelativeSize(int widthGrowFactor, int heightGrowFactor);

    public void setWidth(float width);
    public void setHeight(float height);
}
```

... and more (Updateable, Drawable, Collideable).

Some Entities can rotate/be drawn but not move/collide/update/resize: "static" non-touchable things such as background animations (clouds, sun, stars).

Some entities can move/rotate/be drawn/update/collide/resize: the player characters and monsters.

Some entities can only be drawn: the HUD for the game.

Some entities can move/be drawn/update/collide but not rotate/resize: gun shots for example.

As you can see I have a need for combinations of the above features and it would easily be solved with some multiple inheritance.

Why not do it with interfaces you ask? Because that would leave me copy/pasting a LOT of code for all the methods and creating new types of Entity classes would introduce copy/pasta forever.

You might ask why I wouldn't just create a subclass that could do it all and then override the methods that aren't supposed to work with empty methods or throw a UnsupportedOperationException in those that are invalid? This is still copy/paste even though it's a single line in each method. An Entity that can only `move()` might end up with 50 methods with "throw new UnsupportedOperationException();" and that is unacceptable.

If you suggest Adapter pattern I hope you will post an example of how Adapter Pattern does anything like this (I had a debate about it already).

If you suggest composition please explain how I will get access to the protected fields.

Thanks!

Comment: what you describe can easily be realized using interfaces instead of subclassing. A further way would be to use object-composission rather then inheritance. If you have multiple implementations of an interface that use the same "code" you can refactor the code into an Action f.e. and then pass the implementation to the concrete action (something like a command pattern)

Comment: Feel free to show how.

Comment: Looks like this'd be a lot easier with a "has-a" relationship (has-a Location, has-a Size) than trying to do it with inheritance.

Comment: The problems with this would leave all instances having the same methods and in those instances where a cloud is not collideable what do you suggest I do in those methods? throw unsupportedexceptions? I already debated this solution in my question.

Comment: You have eliminated all Java offers. If you're unhappy with its impoverished abstraction models, leave it. Java simply doesn't have elegant ways to do things like this.

Comment: After having read all of your posts here a couple of times now I think you've already decided to switch to C/C++ (as it is the preferred language for game programming anyway). Here you will not have to deal with the single-class-inheritance limitation and will have more exclusive capabilities on using the computer hardware. Furthermore, you are already optimizing your code before it is even written. You care on the execution of 3 additional lines that are executed in almost no-op time - in my opinion not the best part to start with

Comment: You may be interested to know that with java 8 (which I think is released next month) you can achieve a safe form of multiple inheritance as interfaces are being allowed [default methods](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.6.2/H.html) whereby interfaces can have method bodies which are used unless the implementing class provides its own implementation

Comment: You can also switch to Scala which is a less violent change than moving to C/C++, interoperates more easily with Java code, and supports full multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

As Roman said in the comment:

Java does permit multiple inheritance of `interfaces`. If all you need is to inherit the is-a relationship and a guaranteed set of methods to communicate with the object, this works perfectly.

Only a single `class` (abstract or not) can be inherited from (along with however many interfaces are desired). This is to avoid the complications of "diamond inheritance" -- websearch that phrase to learn more. The usual workaround if you do need to reuse logic from several sources is to define the additional shared behaviors in a utility class, and have your class delegate to an instance of that. Yes, this is a has-a rather than is-a relationship, but since is-a can be abstracted out into an interface you can get the desired final appearance of combined behaviors. (And unlike diamond inheritance, this forces you to make explicit decisions about which implementation you want to invoke.)

Comment: My title should show you that I know multiple inheritance is not allowed. I also write about using multiple interfaces and the problems with it.

Comment: Utility classes address your objections, I believe. The alternative is to leave Java.

Comment: @keshlam or wait a couple of months for java 8 and [interface default methods](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.6.2/H.html)

Comment: Great (he says, sarcastically). Diamond inheritance, here we come. OK, it has a specific resolution rule, but that's not going to keep people from hopelessly confusing themselves.

Comment: @kesham I can see it being wildly misused, but used properly I'm looking forward to it

Comment: I'm not looking forward to supporting people who think they've used it properly, but to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

By contract you are forced to implement the methods defined in an interface. You can however do whatever you like in those methods. In this simple example further implementation classes for `Moveable` and `Rotatable` are created for each instance. Requests for the respective actions are forwarded to the implementations.

This way you can share the same implementation with multiple objects. The action itself is even able to manage its state instead of the delegating class.

```
public SomeClass implements Moveable, Rotatable
{
    // the implementation provide a concrete implementation
    // you can even exchange the implementation with new ones
    private Moveable movaAction = new MoveImpl();
    private Rotatable rotateAction = new RotateImpl();

    public float getVelocityX()
    {
        return moveAction.getVelocityX();
    }

    public void setVelocityX(float velocityX)
    {
        moveAction.getVelocityX(velocityX);
    }

    ...

    public void setAngularVelocity(float degreesPerSecond)
    {
        rotateAction.setAngularVelocity(degreesPerSecond);
    }
    ...
}
```

If you further define f.e. a `registerNewMove(Moveable action)` you can even exchange the concrete implementation (strategy pattern) at runtime if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is the same for all the subclasses, then it could be in the superclass. You could simply do it like this:

```
public final move() {
    if (!isMovable()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This entity can't be moved");
    }
    // TODO implement the actual move
}

public abstract boolean isMovable();
```

If you want to have interfaces to tell if an entity is movable or not, you can even implement the isMovable() method in the superclass:

```
public final boolean isMovable() {
    return this instanceof Movable;
}
```

Comment: This would add the 3 lines with "throw new" in all methods from all 6 interfaces which is currently 19 methods during "design stage". I expect it to grow a lot.

Comment: So what? they're in a single class. If you want a single class with 19 methods, you shouldn't be afraid of having 19 * 3 lines of trivial code. Are you sure all this code should be in the entity itself, and not in a EntityMover class? Are you sure you really want subclasses? If a Sun differs from a Star only by the value of its attributes, why not make everything an instance of Entity, with a different state?

Comment: BackgroundEntity sun = new BackgroundEntity(xxx); BackgroundEntity star = new BackgroundEntity(xxx); They would be the same class, with the same feature set, but different appearance. They don't differ class wise. They can `can rotate/be drawn but not move/collide/update/resize`. The class used for these two differs from the class used to instantiate a bullet because a bullet has a different feature set.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps looking at your problem from a completely different perspective would be useful. Have you considered, instead of building the functionality into the hierarchy of the objects, build the functionality into the initialization of the objects.

Try something like this for a start:

```
static class Thing {
    int x;
    int y;
    float w;
    float h;
    float angle;

}

enum Op {
    Translate{
        @Override
        void op (Thing it, Thing op) {
            it.x += op.x;
            it.y += op.y;
        }
    },
    Rotate{
        @Override
        void op (Thing it, Thing op) {
            it.angle += op.angle;
        }
    },
    Scale{
        @Override
        void op (Thing it, Thing op) {
            it.w *= op.w;
            it.h *= op.h;
        }
    };

    abstract void op(Thing it, Thing op);
}
```

Now you have a base class `Thing` that can be operated on. Building the *legal* operations now becomes a data processing problem rather than a hierarchy problem.

Comment: That assumes that the data that needs to change is already present in the original object. It isn't. If it isn't Drawable it doesn't have a texture and thus setTexture()/getTexture()/draw() methods cannot rely on already present member fields because the extension is supposed to add them. Your solution asks me to put all possible fields into the base class (you put x,y,h,w,angle in your example) that I might need. If I do that I might aswell add the methods for them too. Further example: A Collideable object has a collisiondetector (a rough or a precise algorithm impl) and non-collis do not.

Comment: @Xabster - I suppose the essence of the idea is to point out that you don't actually need to put **all** of the functionality into the classes - you can use *machinery* such as this for example. A well designed mixture of machinery and interface driven inherited functionality can often produce a much more intuitive API. Remember that you should design your objects depending on what they **are** not what they **do**.